# Обобщения дилемма

Tags: c#

С методом разобрался, но почему теперь здесь не создает новый объект? Уж простите меня за непонимание.

```
using System;
interface IA<T>
{
    void Z(T t);
}
class a<T> where T : IA<T>
{
}
class b<T> : IA<T>
{
    public void Z(T t)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(t.GetType().Name);
    }
}
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a<b<int>> A = new a<b<int>>();
    }
}
```

Почему же он не хочет создавать объект, что ему теперь здесь не так?

Comment: @polyakov_s несочтите за труд, но было бы неплохо, если бы вы потрудились давать вашим классам и методам какие-нибудь более-менее адекватные имена -  вникать в то, что  у васза классы такие a, b и с подчас требует времени

Comment: Прошу прощения, больше не повториться. Согласен, что виноват.

Comment: кстати, если планируете работать программистом, то от этой дурной привычки вас в любом случае заставят избавиться

Comment: Согласен. Я и сам не понимаю, неудобоваримый код. Но че-то меня бес попутал

Comment: касательно вопроса - он по сути аналогичен тому, что вы уже задавали пару часов назад, и на который ответил @VladD.

Comment: Целиком согласен, но вот что меня смутило. Я же реализую интерфейс, в классе b, делаю объявление переменной a<b<int>> A, где b<int> заменяет метку T в интерфейсе. То есть все очень даже комильфо. Мое предположение, из-за чего это: потому что класс b реализует IA<T>, а не какой-то закрытый тип, например, <IA><int>. В то время как я в качестве аргумента сую закрытый тип. Но душа чует, что я написал бред.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот эта строчка

```
class a<T> where T : IA<T>
```

накладывает на генерик-параметр ограничение - подставляемый класс `T` должен реализовать интерфейс `IA<T>`

Т.е. если вы подставляете туда класс `SomeClass`, то `SomeClass` должен быть объявлен как

```
class SomeClass : IA<SomeClass> { ...
```

Класс `b<int>` такому ограничению явно не соответствует - он реализует `IA<int>`, а не `IA<b<int>>`.

То, что метки (генерик-параметры) в классах называются одинаково - ничего не значит. `T` в контексте класса `a<T>` - это совсем не то же самое, что `T` в контексте класса `b<T>`.

<sub>в рамках закрытия старых неотвеченных вопросов</sub>